# AlarmManager doesn't wake up device

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I set the alarm  like this:

```
registerReceiver(wakeUpReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.example.yay"));
pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent("com.example.yay"), 0);
am = (AlarmManager)(getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE));

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    am.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+30*1000, pi);
} else {
    am.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+30*1000, pi);
}
```

And it works if the device is awake, but if I turn off the screen, it doesn't turn on the screen (but wakeUpReceiver's onReceive() gets called)

What do I need to put in the manifest? AlarmManager docs don't seem to mention anything relevant to permissions or intent filter or anything like that. Maybe I'm just misunderstanding the docs as usual?

And yes, I've read all the other similar questions, but they're not helping.

Comment: Go to the Activity which you want to start in onReceive(). Paste this in onCreate() of that Activity

final Window win= getWindow(); win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD); win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

Answer (score 0):

You can use Wakelock to achieve this:

**Different Levels Wake Locks:**

> FULL_WAKE_LOCK -  Keep the screen at full brightness, keyboard
>   back-light illuminated, and the CPU running. SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK -
>   Keeps the screen at full brightness and the CPU running.
>   SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK - Keeps the screen ON but lets it dim and the CPU
>   running. PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK -  Keeps the CPU running

**Android permission for Wakelock:**

Since wake locks has huge impact on battery life your application needs to request WAKE_LOCK permission in order to create them.

**Create Wake Locks**
To create a wake lock call newWakeLock on the Power manger as follows:

```
PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock ;
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
 wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock( PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My wakelook");
```

**Release Wake lock**

```
wakeLock.release();
```

Its very important to release wakelock or else it will drain the battery.

Answer (score 0):

As answered above use wakelock create WakeLock in     onReceive().

Or I suggest you to use [WakefulBroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html). 
This will make sure that ur phone is awake during service.

WakefulBroadcastReceiver is the best option for the 2nd thing, about wakelocks - u can check on google some examples that show how to use alarm manager with wakelocks.
Ofc, ur service can done it's work, but sometimes sleep can occour, so I suggest you to implement it even if ur tests don't show the problem, better too keep it safe.

Are you sure     onReceive() being called? Create some logs and do some tests. For now there can be 2 problems: or sleep is not calling     onReceive() (here check the power managment options on your phone, I had problem with "Stamina" on my phone, which was blocking my alarms) or your phone is falling asleep before u do your work (then wakelocks/WakefulBroadcastReceiver).

Also AlarmManager will not "light up" ur screen, only CPU.

To turn on the screen use    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
or     android:keepScreenOn="true" in layout.

The method suggested by another user     SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK was deprecated in API level 17, keep it in mind!

For more:
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html